# rxjs subscribe doesn't return response from angular2 service

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am trying to render a table using data returned from a service but the subscribe callback I am using is not able to set the data to the components scope but it shows up when I log the data.

My service method has the map and the catch methods

```
generateReport(rate){
  return this.post(`/reports/owl/${this.deviceId}/electricity/tables`,this.query)
             .map(res => res.json())
             .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error  || { error: 'Server error' }) );
}
```

and on the component class

```
private generateReport(){
     this.dataService.generateReport(this.carbonRate)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                      this.rows = data.rows;
                      this.columns = data.columns;
                      this.showDownload = true;
                    },this.errorHandler);

    }
```

The code above would stop everything on the browser window until the browser decides to stop the process.

but if do a `console.log()` inside the success callback

```
this.dataService.generateReport(this.carbonRate)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                      console.log(data);
                    },this.errorHandler);
```

The screen doesn't freeze up and I can access the data returned.

Comment: Well, this looks like you have a problem with the data when rendering them and not when processing but it's impossible to give any advice from this description. Can you make a demo?

Comment: Yep, it looks like the issue is caused by whatever happens with that data within your component. Could you post your component's logic and template code?

Comment: I am using ngx-datatable, if that helps. Ill try to make a plunk and share